# How to Handle '&' in Node.js to avoid XSS vulnerability

Tags: node.js, angular, xss, ampersand

We are having a Angular 2+ UI and Backend in Node.js
There are some HTML input need to allow '&' character but Node.js is not allowing it because it using HTML-sanitize to validate the inputs fields.
How to allow the '&' store in Database.

Comment: Are you using this? https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html

Comment: Yes, correct @connexo

Answer (score 0):

[sanitize-html](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html) replaces `&` with the corresponding HTML entity `&amp;`; it does not totally remove the `&`.

You are free to do whatever you want with the sanitized input before storing it in your database, so what you could do is replace it back:

```
const restoredString = sanitizedString.replaceAll('&amp;', '&');
```